# Controller property change doesn't affect the whole bound property on some directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-1.5

Let's say I've implemented a directive as follows:

```
module.directive("foo", function($scope) {
      return {
          controllerAs: "model",
          controller: function($scope) {
              this.items = $scope.items;

              this.selectItem = function(item) {
                   this.selectedItem = item;
              };
          },
          scope: { items: "=" }
      };
});

module.directive("bar", function($scope) {
      return {
          controllerAs: "model",
          controller: function() { 
               this.item = $scope.item;
          },
          scope: { item: "=" }
      };
});
```

...where *foo* directive's template would look as follows:

```
<bar item="model.selectedItem" />
<ol>
<li ng-repeat="item in model.items" ng-click="model.selectItem(item)">
    <bar item="item" />
</li>
</ol>
```

...and `bar` directive's template would look as:

```
<span ng-bind="item.text"></span>
```

### TL;DR: My issue

When `model.selectedItem` changes because user has clicked on some *repeated* `<bar />`, the outer `<bar />` is unaware of any the so-called property change. That is, the outer `<bar />` won't update its bound `model.text` property.

I can't figure out why a model change on `foo`'s controller won't change the outer `bar` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedItem` lives in the `foo` directives scope. Therfor, it won't be visible to the outside(the `bar` directive).

You could keep another variable containing the key of the selected item. 
Then in the `bar` directive you can bind the value as follows,

```
<bar item ="items[selectedKey].text"></bar>
```

edit: You could also try, setting the value on the scope rather than on `this`.

```
$scope.selectedItem = item;
```

Instead of

```
this.selectedItem = item;
```

Comment: But AFAIK `model.selectedItem` is bound to `<bar>` and it's passed as a two-way binding property, shouldn't be bar's scope be aware of the whole property changes?

Comment: Your approach worked fine, BTW as I said in my previous comment, I expected that giving a property, either from $scope or from the controller alias should work.

Comment: You define an isolated scope for the directive and it only contains `scope: { items: "=" }`, I believe that the directive only has access to that specific object.

Comment: It's strange, but we can't change Angular behavior ;P